# Kohana 3.1 ORM Security Question

Tags: orm, kohana

Are all values escaped when using the ORM Module?

For example, if I have:

```
$user->where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->request-post('user') . '%')->find_all()
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ORM uses the [query builder](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder), which automatically escapes all values.

> Creating queries dynamically using objects and methods allows queries to
>   be written very quickly in an agnostic
>   way. Query building also adds
>   identifier (table and column name)
>   quoting, as well as value quoting.